# Why don't projects created using git source control show in the Source control explorer

Tags: git, tfs, team-project

If you create a Team project and you use git as the source control provider the new project does no show up in the Source Control Explorer. Other projects in the same team project collection appear, but these are using TFS as the version control provider.

Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Source Control Explorer is not available for Git projects. If you connect to a Git project you'll see that the Source Control Explorer option is not available from the Team Explorer.

Comment: thanks, hopefully in a later version we might see some integration. One could see the hassles however. Branching and merging is done differently. I would like the ability to be able to branch my TFS project to a git one though. (I do know it's possible to convert them without losing commit history)